# Android - Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]

Tags: android, build, installation

I'm having some really strange behaviour in Android Studio. Each time I try to install my app through usb debug I get the error

> pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.blabla.blabla
>   Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED]

I read that the quickest method to resolve this problem is to delete the data folder of the app, but:
1) My phone (Samsung Galaxy S2 Plus) is not rooted
2) I **never installed the app**! So there can't be a data folder!!

I encounter this problem also with the simpliest default Hello World Activity Application. I tried to uninstall/reinstall Android Studio, update the SDK (now I have version 21) and to make a factory reset of my phone, but nothing works.

I'm really stuck, can somebody give me an hand? Thank you a lot

Comment: You did reboot your computer did you? Or at least restarted adb? I had something like that just today, I think this is an ADB issue introduced lately.

Comment: I just rebooted but the result is the same. I just ask myself why a so widely-spread os doesn't have a super cool ide which is not beta and hasn't lots of bugs... It seems like Google doesn't want us to develop for android

Comment: No need to rant. :) They really are trying it seems to me... switch to intellij etc. What version of Android Studio are you using? Have you tried to switch back to older version. As I said I just had the same issue today, but unfortunately im not sure how I got rid of it.

Comment: Sometimes Android makes me crazy :) I have the latest version of Android Studio (0.8.6)

Comment: I understand :) btw latest studio is at 0.8.13 (canary channel!)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about this site, I'll try the newest version!

Comment: Same problem... I think I'm going to nuke everything

Comment: Dont give up. Try to figure out the issue, it can be a serious bug, maybe you can get real fame here.